# If, else statements in PHP

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

Problem with writing an if-else statement for a sports website. The key is to display `$game` as `W`, `L`, or `Tie` depending on the scores which are parsed from a MySQL table from a variable called `$row["result"]`. The type of the column in table is VARCHAR and format the data saved in is `$row["result"] = "A:B"` where A is the home team's score and B is the opponents score. I am running into a problem where I write the if statement I can only echo Wins (W) and Ties (Tie) correctly!

For example the code:

```
<?php
$wl = $row["result"];
if ($wl[1] > $wl[3]) {
  $game = "W";
}
if ($wl[1] < $wl[3]) {
  $game = "L";
}
if ($wl[1] == $wl[3]) {
  $game = "Tie";
}
?>
```

`$game` will output correctly when `$wl= A>B` and `A==B` but not `A<B`. I have a feeling this has something to do with PHP interpreting the data from `$wl` as not numbers, but some other format...

Comment: Just a suggestion. But you will find your programs far easier if you use meaningful variable names.  $wl might seem oubvious to you now, but in a year you will wish you had used $win_loss.  Don't worry about typying long variable names, a decent IDE (like NetBeans - probably teh best for PHP (Ymmv)) will autocomplete variable names

Comment: did you miss a few words at the end?  "but not A...."  (perhaps not A<B ?)

Comment: I suppose it's a waste of time suggesting that your database schema is dodgy. If you _ever_ find yourself in a situation when you're having to process parts of columns, that's usually the case.

Comment: put "else" between the ifs and at the end a final else for error reporting. var_dump($wl). I suspect that you might have invalid data. Can you post it here?

Comment: Btw, something like dbug (http://dbug.ospinto.com/) will "pretty print" and is more useful than var_dump() for nested arrays

Comment: Gotcha!  What if the home team scores more than 9 goals?  The away team's score is no longer $wl[3].  Listen to @paxdiablo (for whom, +1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd also recommend using explode(), but for what you're using I think you should be referencing $wl[0] and $wl[2], since the array $wl starts at zero index.

Comment: This is precisely my problem. Although now I have decided to explode the result so I have to use $wl[0] and $wl[1]. AND IT WORKS! Thank you!

Comment: Good decision :-) Glad to help!

Answer (score 4):

Try using "else if" instead of "if" on the last two "if" conditions. Also are you explode()'ing the result?

```
$wl = explode(':', $row['result']);
$wl[0] = Score for team A
$wl[1] = Score for team B
```

Comment: Thank you! So if I am right what the explode function does is separate the variables divided by the colon ':' so if a team scores more than 9 goals the code will function correctly? If so, what a powerful PHP feature!

Answer (score 1):

Or here, if you want it in a cryptic way

```
 $wl = explode(":",$row["result"]);
 $game = ($wl[0]>$wl[1])?"W":(($wl[0]<$wl[1])?"L":"TIE");
```